# React native where to load fonts?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I have an Splash screen with an animation, and my app has custom fonts. My question is: where should I load the fonts? In App.js or in the splash screen?

I want to start the splash screen animation only when te fonts are loaded and the user auth state is checked. Talking about performance... should I delegate all this action to the splash screen?

Answer (score 0):

The best place to load necessary data is just before the application is mounted.

In other words, we should delay mounting the application before all the 'dependencies' are gathered and set. That's what splash screens are for - they act as the only interim screen between your application entrance & the first engageable screen. I would combine the two, and display the splash screen while the data is loading - when it's mounted and loaded it behaves as previously set in the 'AppContainer' definition.

*App.js*

```
...
state: {
 isLoadingComplete: false
}

componentDidMount = async() => {
 //load all your async data & update the flag when finished
 this.setState({isLoadingComplete: true})
}

...
render(){
 if (!this.state.isLoadingComplete) {
  ...display your loading animation
 } else {
  <App/>
 }
}
```

App itself, at least most of the time for me, is basically a 'switchNavigator' - only ever displaying one set of screens depending on your auth flow & logic.

This medium article offers interesting insight into the Splash Screen subject & it's purpose:

https://blog.mobile-patterns.com/splash-screen-designing-a-successful-launch-experience-for-your-mobile-app-b0b70a0ef32d

Hope it helps.

Comment: My final decision has been to delegate the fonts load, firebase fetch, etc. in my Splash Screen... I did it just to not overload my App.js with a lot of states and to start the splash animation when all the requirements are loaded. I don't know if it is the best option but works... Should I move it again to App.js? What do you think?

Comment: That is fine, but Im still bothered with two distinct loading screens. Why wouldn't that be one screen? It all comes down to user experience, and the established practices that users are used too. Anyway, I doubt it takes a lot of time, even for two screens, so just go with it.

Comment: Nooo!! There is only one loading screen, the splash. In App.js I have a conditional render which decides what to show (the splash or the content) based on the isLoading state, which is modified by the Splash (child of App)

Answer (score 0):

Then all is good! That's how I would do it.